# Given an abelian Group how to define the Endomorphism Ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have to construct the Endomorphism Ring based on the group $(\mathbb{Z}_{2},+)$. What I know is that given an abelian group G then End(G) with $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ and $(fg)(x)=f(g(x))$ is the Endomorphism Ring but I can't understand how this can help me to construct $End(\mathbb{Z}_{2})$

Comment: If by $\mathbb{Z}_2$ you mean the ring $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, have you thought about how many elements it has? Or maybe can you say something about what happens to the element $0$ under homomorpisms? The endomorphisms of this ring can be computed by hand quite easily.

Comment: @Nephry Yes, I was referring to it. It has 2 elements ${\bar{0},\bar{1}}$ If $\bar{0}$ is the neutral element then $\phi(\bar{0})=\bar{0}$ right? Then $\phi(\bar{1})$ had to be $\bar{1}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before trying to understand the endomorphism *ring*, try to understand the *set* of endomorphisms.  Since $\mathbb{Z}_2$ has only two elements, this isn't so bad to do by brute force: there are only four different functions $f:\mathbb{Z}_2\to\mathbb{Z}_2$.  You can list them out and check them one-by-one to see which ones are homomorphisms (you should get that two of them are homomorphisms).  Once you've identified the homomorphisms, you can then determine the ring operations on them by the formulas you gave in the question.

Comment: The two homomorphisms are $\phi(\bar{0})=\bar{0},\phi(\bar{1})=\bar{1}$ and $\phi(\bar{0})=\bar{0},\phi(\bar{1})=\bar{0}$?

Comment: That's right. You should give them different names, though.

Comment: Thanks for the indications :)